# Applescript (or other Quicksilver accessible thing) for hibernating a snow leopard mac?

Tags: sleep-wake

Anyone have a quick way, accessible from Quicksilver, to force your mac to hibernate?

Comment: Instead of Quicksilver, why dont you try [Alfred.app](http://www.alfredapp.com)? It provides basic system commands such as sleep, trash, logout etc, you can customize it pretty easily and its full of nifty features!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Deep Sleep**](http://deepsleep.free.fr/). It's a Dashboard widget that will put your mac into hibernation mode.

**Edit**: from the website

> Deep Sleep can also be used as a [command line utility](http://deepsleep.free.fr/ds.zip)

From there, you can check out if QuickSilver can launch command line programs.
You can also package it in a `.app` -for example using Automator- and launch it with QuickSilver.

~~

**Careful**, be aware there's 2 sleep mode.

The normal one you can trigger using <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>

And the hibernate (or Safe Sleep) mode.

You can read about the differences between them [here](http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/computers-sleep.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I've been using that widget for awhile now. What I'm looking for is something that I can access via Quicksilver.

Comment: @Tim I added a solution for Quicksilver

Comment: Shame on me for not noticing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install [SleepNow](http://www.snoize.com/SleepNow/) and then run that from QuickSilver.

Comment: SleepNow just puts the computer to sleep. That option is available by default in Quicksilver's Extra Scripts plug-in. The original poster asked for a script to force hibernation.